# sed | awk : Keep end of String until special character is reached

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to cut a HDD ID's in sed to just contain the serial number of the drive. The ID's looks like:

```
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD30EFRX2D68EUZN0_________________________WD2DWMC4N2575116
```

So, I only want to keep the "WD2DWMC4N2575116". Serial numbers are not fixed length so I tried to keep the last character until the first "_" appears. Unfortunately I suck at RegExp :(

Comment: `I tried to keep the last character until the first "_" appears` please add whatever code that you tried to question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture all characters after last `_`, using backreference:

```
$ sed 's/.*_\(.*\)/\1/' <<< "t10.ATA_____WDC_WD30EFRX2D68EUZN0_________________________WD2DWMC4N2575116"
WD2DWMC4N2575116
```

Or as pointed out in comment, you can just remove all characters from beginning of the line up to last `_`:

```
sed 's/.*_//' file
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you very much! Woking great now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "t10.ATA_____WDC_WD30EFRX2D68EUZN0_________________________WD2DWMC4N2575116" | rev | awk -F '_' '{print $1}' | rev
```

It works only if the ID is at the end.

Comment: you can simplify to get last field instead... `awk -F'_' '{print $NF}'`

Comment: Didn't use awk for a while :) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk, this time using `sub`:

Data:

```
$ cat file
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD30EFRX2D68EUZN0_________________________WD2DWMC4N2575116
```

Code + result:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^.*_/,"")' file
WD2DWMC4N2575116
```

ie. replace everything from the first character to the last `_`. As `sub` returns the number of substitutions made, that value is used to trigger the implicit output. If you have several records to process and not all of them have `_`s, add `||1` after the `sub`:

```
$ cat foo >> file
$ awk 'sub(/^.*_/,"") || 1' file
WD2DWMC4N2575116
foo
```